# Click event does not return $event on click

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following structure in my HTML in an angular 7 application:

What I am trying to do is to call the GetContent() function on click of any of the text inside the div. I am able to get the $event as "Liquidity" when I click on the text but if I click on any empty space between the text, the $event is empty. I tried every possible permutation of changing the location of the function call and id but same issue. Can anyone let me know what is wrong.

```
<tr (click)="GetContent($event)">
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
     <td> 
      <div id="Liquidity"> lot of text....................... </div> 
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
<tr>
```

Comment: <tr (click)="GetContent($event)">
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div id="Liquidity"> lot of text.......................
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
<tr>

Comment: are u sure the table structure is correct ? the table tag should be outside `tr` if there is no nesting.

Comment: If the function is called the **$event** will not be empty, it will return click event properties with target (clicked element). Could you please provide **stackblitz**

Comment: @YogeshMali try below solution.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hc9tsr If you click on the space between the lines ( the mouse changes to pointer ), $event is not available

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way , 
**UPDATED**

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
       <td> 
          <div id="Liquidity" (click)="GetContent($event)"> lot of text....................... </div> 
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**ts file**

```
GetContent(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
     console.log(value) //you will get liquid here.
  }
```

Comment: Hi Pushprajsinh, I tried your solution but target.attributes.id comes as undefined when I click on the blank space

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no content in your TR's and TD's, its not creating a space at all. Look at my code, I have added padding for table row's ,table and table data tags

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr (click)="GetContent($event)" >
            <td style="padding:20px;background:red">TD
                <table style="padding:20px;background:green">Table
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:20px;background:blue">TD
                                <div id="Liquidity" style="padding:10px;background:green"> lot of text....................... </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixq7mq)